# Priority REST: My GET requests are getting http reponse 200 but no actual data inside

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I am new to Priority but working with their REST API to get form information I need. As per the REST API docs I use Basic Authentication with a GET request to the service root (I believe in my projects case it would be the url I use to access the Priority software on the web), however while the HTTP GET request succeeds, nothing is returned.

The API docs state that a basic call to the Service Root should :  **returns a basic list of the resources available through the service.**

However nothing is returned in JSON format when I make a GET request but the 200 response is returned. This is unlike when I make a call to the example service root listed on the docs (https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui/odata/Priority/tabmob.ini/usdemo/), which returns a JSON object with the intended output.

Does this mean I do not have any services available? How do I enable them? Apologies as it is my first time using priority and I am unsure why this has been so arduous to figure out.

Thank you!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66648769/7334025

Answer (score 1):

The API endpoint is not the same as the Priority user interface URL.
You need to send yourself the API endpoint from within Priority - in the Users menu you have a program that sends the API uri.

Also, you need the API module license, and API user license associated to your r Priority user.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is the Users menu only available if you have the API licenses? I don't see any mention of this in the user manual. Thank you!