# Priority REST API - Generating key for API Access

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I am new to Priority and can't seem to find in the docs where I can generate an API key for accessing the REST API. It was my understanding that a user has to have the API license key enabled (which my user does).. But where can I generate the link? Is there any good resource to find this out? I've scoured the docs and while they mention using it I didn't see any mention of how to generate the endpoint to send requests to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is a Procedure named `"Send Program Activation Link"`
   (internal name MGLINK) you can run to receive the link.
2. It usually looks like this:
   https://priority.web.url/odata/Priority/tabula.inifile/envCode
3. The API Username (on USERSB form) and the Priority user's password are
   needed for the Authorization header.

Comment: Thank you for that. If you have time for a follow up question, when I connect to the API and try to add the 'url' property to the end of the API : ex. 
   https://priority.web.url/odata/Priority/tabula.inifile/envCode/ORDERS, I get 'Cannot run API for this screen'. This is not the case for the test API configuration.

Comment: Looks to be a 403 forbidden issue.

Comment: You need to flag this form in FORMLIMITED form (Limited Access/API Forms) as "Open for API)